# How do I detect if a category has Include in Navigation Menu set to NO?

Tags: magento

How do I detect if a category has **Include in Navigation Menu** set to NO?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`include_in_menu` is an attribute so you can use,

```
if (!$category->getIncludeInMenu()) ...
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

```
 $category->load();
//$category->getIncludeInMenu() returns 1 if set to yes, returns 0 if set to no
if(!$category->getIncludeInMenu())
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading entire object (performance issue) there is a better way of checking if category has include_in_menu attribute:

```
    $Category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->addFieldToFilter('parent_id', $rootCategory)
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1)
                        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('id', 'name', 'url','include_in_menu'))
                        ->setOrder('position','ASC');
```

This way you will load only attributes which are required to build navigation.