# Magento Category model not loading all data

Tags: magento

I am building a custom navigation menu in Magento which displays the categories from a different store with a different root category from the current store. Some of the categories should be hidden as they have 'Include in Navigation Menu' set to No.

It should be possible to read this attribute from the category model as in this question: [How do I detect if a category has Include in Navigation Menu set to NO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708266/how-do-i-detect-if-a-category-has-include-in-navigation-menu-set-to-no)

However $category->getIncludeInMenu() is returning NULL for all categories on my Magento EE 1.11 installation.

```
// Load child categories for a specific root category
$_uk_default_root_id = Mage::app()->getStore('uk_default')->getRootCategoryId();
$_uk_default_root_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_uk_default_root_id); 
$_sub_categories = $_uk_default_root_category->getChildrenCategories();

// Loop through the categories
foreach ($_sub_categories as $_category)
{
    if ($_category->getIsActive() && $_category->getIncludeInMenu())
    {
        <echo navigation link>
    }
}
```

A var dump of one of the categories shows no 'include_in_menu' attribute, although the 'is_active' attribute works as expected. Is there an alternative way to determine if a category should be displayed in the navigation?

Var dump of category object:

```
object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category)[423]
  protected '_eventPrefix' => string 'catalog_category' (length=16)
  protected '_eventObject' => string 'category' (length=8)
  protected '_cacheTag' => string 'catalog_category' (length=16)
  protected '_useFlatResource' => boolean false
  private '_designAttributes' => 
    array (size=6)
      0 => string 'custom_design' (length=13)
      1 => string 'custom_design_from' (length=18)
      2 => string 'custom_design_to' (length=16)
      3 => string 'page_layout' (length=11)
      4 => string 'custom_layout_update' (length=20)
      5 => string 'custom_apply_to_products' (length=24)
  protected '_treeModel' => null
  protected '_defaultValues' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected '_storeValuesFlags' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected '_lockedAttributes' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected '_isDeleteable' => boolean true
  protected '_isReadonly' => boolean false
  protected '_resourceName' => string 'catalog/category' (length=16)
  protected '_resource' => null
  protected '_resourceCollectionName' => string 'catalog/category_collection' (length=27)
  protected '_dataSaveAllowed' => boolean true
  protected '_isObjectNew' => null
  protected '_data' => 
    array (size=15)
      'entity_id' => string '16' (length=2)
      'entity_type_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'attribute_set_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'parent_id' => string '15' (length=2)
      'created_at' => string '2011-11-16 12:16:27' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2011-12-19 16:19:08' (length=19)
      'path' => string '1/15/16' (length=7)
      'position' => string '1' (length=1)
      'level' => string '2' (length=1)
      'children_count' => string '8' (length=1)
      'is_active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'request_path' => null
      'name' => string 'Vacuum Cleaners' (length=15)
      'url_key' => string 'vacuum-cleaners' (length=15)
      'is_anchor' => string '1' (length=1)
  protected '_hasDataChanges' => boolean true
  protected '_origData' => 
    array (size=15)
      'entity_id' => string '16' (length=2)
      'entity_type_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'attribute_set_id' => string '3' (length=1)
      'parent_id' => string '15' (length=2)
      'created_at' => string '2011-11-16 12:16:27' (length=19)
      'updated_at' => string '2011-12-19 16:19:08' (length=19)
      'path' => string '1/15/16' (length=7)
      'position' => string '1' (length=1)
      'level' => string '2' (length=1)
      'children_count' => string '8' (length=1)
      'is_active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'request_path' => null
      'name' => string 'Vacuum Cleaners' (length=15)
      'url_key' => string 'vacuum-cleaners' (length=15)
      'is_anchor' => string '1' (length=1)
  protected '_idFieldName' => string 'entity_id' (length=9)
  protected '_isDeleted' => boolean false
  protected '_oldFieldsMap' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  protected '_syncFieldsMap' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Comment: Your var dump doesn't show the object. What object is $_category? The first step is to verify the object should have the property/method you wish to use.

Comment: The object is a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category`. I've updated the var dump to show the full object.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is due to Magento lazy loading the category model. The `getChildrenCategories()` method on the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` model returns a collection of category models and Magento only loads the core model data rather than the additional EAV data for each model. The `include_in_menu` attribute is stored in the EAV data store and has not been loaded.

Each category can be forced to load by calling `$_category->load();` which will force Magento to load the additional EAV data for each category.

```
// Loop through the categories
foreach ($_sub_categories as $_category)
{
    $_category->load();
    if ($_category->getIsActive() && $_category->getIncludeInMenu())
    {
        <echo navigation link>
    }
}
```

This changes the `_data` array from this:

```
array (size=15)
  'entity_id' => string '16' (length=2)
  'entity_type_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'attribute_set_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'parent_id' => string '15' (length=2)
  'created_at' => string '2011-11-16 12:16:27' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2011-12-19 16:19:08' (length=19)
  'path' => string '1/15/16' (length=7)
  'position' => string '1' (length=1)
  'level' => string '2' (length=1)
  'children_count' => string '8' (length=1)
  'is_active' => string '1' (length=1)
  'request_path' => null
  'name' => string 'Vacuum Cleaners' (length=15)
  'url_key' => string 'vacuum-cleaners' (length=15)
  'is_anchor' => string '1' (length=1)
```

To this:

```
array (size=33)
  'entity_id' => string '16' (length=2)
  'entity_type_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'attribute_set_id' => string '3' (length=1)
  'parent_id' => string '15' (length=2)
  'created_at' => string '2011-11-16 12:16:27' (length=19)
  'updated_at' => string '2011-12-19 16:19:08' (length=19)
  'path' => string '1/15/16' (length=7)
  'position' => string '1' (length=1)
  'level' => string '2' (length=1)
  'children_count' => string '8' (length=1)
  'is_active' => string '1' (length=1)
  'request_path' => null
  'name' => string 'Vacuum Cleaners' (length=15)
  'url_key' => string 'vacuum-cleaners' (length=15)
  'is_anchor' => string '1' (length=1)
  'meta_title' => null
  'display_mode' => string 'PRODUCTS' (length=8)
  'custom_design' => null
  'page_layout' => null
  'url_path' => string 'vacuum-cleaners' (length=15)
  'image' => string 'heading_vacuums_1.png' (length=21)
  'include_in_menu' => string '1' (length=1)
  'landing_page' => null
  'custom_use_parent_settings' => string '0' (length=1)
  'custom_apply_to_products' => string '0' (length=1)
  'filter_price_range' => null
  'description' => null
  'meta_keywords' => null
  'meta_description' => null
  'custom_layout_update' => null
  'available_sort_by' => null
  'custom_design_from' => null
  'custom_design_to' => null
```

Which includes the `include_in_menu` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use:

$_category->load($_category->getId());

worked for me ;)