# How do I render Categorys with Include in Navigation Menu set to "No"?

Tags: php, magento, render, nav, categories

I got this code so far:

```
function render_flat_nav($categories) {
    $html = '<ul>';
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $html .= '<li>('.$category->getId().') '.utf8_decode($category->getName()) . "\n";
        if($category->hasChildren()) {
            $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category', array('disable_flat' => true))->getCategories($category->entity_id);
            $html .= render_flat_nav($children);
        }
        $html .= '</li>';
    }
    return $html . '</ul>';
}
```

How can I also render the Categories with **Include in Navigation** Menu set to **NO** ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708266/how-do-i-detect-if-a-category-has-include-in-navigation-menu-set-to-no  +  https://tzamtzis.gr/2011/magento/magento-list-categories-which-have-the-option-include-in-navigation-menu-set-to-no/  Maybe it helps? :)